# Programmatically turn off logging revel framework

Tags: logging, go, revel

How can I programatically turn of logs like the one below. I need this to be able to run my testsuites with out filling the test logs with warnings and info logs.

```
revel.INFO.printf("")
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From package [`revel`](http://godoc.org/github.com/revel/revel) you have:

> ```
> var (
>     // Loggers
>     TRACE = log.New(ioutil.Discard, "TRACE ", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
>     INFO  = log.New(ioutil.Discard, "INFO  ", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
>     WARN  = log.New(ioutil.Discard, "WARN  ", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
>     ERROR = log.New(&error_log, "ERROR ", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
> )
> ```

From package [`log`](http://godoc.org/log) you have:

> func New
>
> ```
> func New(out io.Writer, prefix string, flag int) *Logger
> ```
>
> New creates a new Logger. The out variable sets the destination to
>   which log data will be written. The prefix appears at the beginning of
>   each generated log line. The flag argument defines the logging
>   properties.

From package [`ioutil`](http://godoc.org/?q=ioutil) you have:

> ```
> var Discard io.Writer = devNull(0)
> ```
>
> Discard is an io.Writer on which all Write calls succeed without doing
>   anything.

Therefore, to turn off the `revel.INFO` log try:

```
revel.INFO = log.New(ioutil.Discard, "INFO  ", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
```

Comment: Composition for the win! :)

Comment: Great answer! Thank you. I will definatley use it allthough for now I turned off the log by simply setting all writes to null.